# Custom shaped graphs using javascript library

Tags: javascript, css, graph, raphael, graphael

Is there a way i can make shape of a dialogue bubble and show the statistics inside that dialogue bubble in raphael js

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Rafael syntax seems similar to HTML5 canvas. You should be able to just create stroke coordinates to draw the shape of the bubble as you would like it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

Graphael provides a few default methods for text bubbles:

```
Raphael.fn.g.tag(x,y,text,angle,r)
Raphael.fn.g.flag(x,y,text,angle)
Raphael.fn.g.label(x,y,text)
Raphael.fn.g.blob(x,y,text,angle,size)
Raphael.fn.g.popup(x,y,text,dir,size)
```

so, for example...

```
window.onload = function(){
     var r = Raphael('graph');
     var flag = r.flag(100,100,"Hello!",15);
}
```

If those don't cut the mustard, then you will want to create your own svg path. You might then want to check out some paths Dmitry has made available here: http://raphaeljs.com/icons/